# Replace several words with other words using "sed"

Tags: text-processing, sed

How do I change multiple words using `sed`? For example, I have a plain text file with the contents being

```
Var_A = 1
Var_B = 2
Var_C = 3
```

How do I change `1`, `2` and `3` to `AAA`, `BBB` and `CCC` so that the resulting file looks like this:

```
Var_A = AAA
Var_B = BBB
Var_C = CCC
```

I've tried using this

```
sed -i 's/Var_A = 1\nVar_B = 2\nVar_C = 3/Var_A = AAA\nVar_B = BBB\nVar_C = CCC' file.txt
```

but it does not work at all.

Comment: Welcome to the site. It is likely that `sed` is not the right tool for the purpose, but we would need more details. In particular: where do you define the mapping between `1` and `AAA` etc.? Is it stored in a file? Please don't post requested details in the comment section ,but edit your question to add them so that all contributors have the complete picture at a glance.

Comment: I have a random .txt file with the only contents being
`
Var_A = 1
Var_B = 2
Var_C = 3
`

I was hoping if there was a way to replace 1,2,3 in that .txt file

Comment: I understand that, but is there a second file that says "`1` should be replaced by `AAA`" and "`2` should be replaced by `BBB`" etc.? If not, how do you want to specify that mapping? Is it all part of a larger shell script where you have that stored as shell variables? The problem in understanding your question is that the way you currently describe it, it sounds easier to simply rewrite the file rather than try to edit it, so I'm pretty sure we are still missing details here ;)

Comment: There's not specific mapping here. All I'm trying to do is replace multiple words but because those words have a new line between them I'm not able to accomplish that through the script I posted. Going forward, I want to setup a script I could use (this is a very simply use-case that can be used for lot of purposes) instead of manually opening the file and making edits (why would I want to rewrite a file? let say my txt file has millions lines of codes rewriting that file makes no sense).

Comment: Of course you don't actually want to rewrite your file. I get that. The problem is that from your description it doesn't become clear what the best solution for your use case actually is, because while you certainly don't want to rewrite a file with millions of lines of code, you will also probably not want to compose a `sed` command with millions of individual substitution arguments. That is why I was asking for more details.

Comment: @Geralt: What we need to understand is what are your _mapping_ requirements? Do you _always_ want to replace "1" with "AAA", "2" with "BBB", and "3" with "CCC", regardless? I.E., what determines what data gets remapped to what other data?

Answer (score 6):

It would seem that you are looking for a basic test case on how to use `sed` for replacing text. In your case, I would propose the following command:

```
sed -e '/^Var_A/s/1/AAA/' -e '/^Var_B/s/2/BBB/' -e '/^Var_B/s/3/CCC/' file.txt
```

This will apply three "targeted" substitution commands that will check if a line starts with `Var_A`, and if so, replace the `1` with `AAA` (and so on).

Answer (score 3):

Let's see if something like this is what you are looking for:

```bsh
# define the replacement variables
$ a='AAA';b='BBB';c='CCC'
# make each replacement using the variables.
$ sed -e "s/^\(Var_A = \).*$/\1$a/" -e "s/^\(Var_B = \).*$/\1$b/" -e "s/^\(Var_C = \).*$/\1$c/" foo.txt 
Var_A = AAA
Var_B = BBB
Var_C = CCC
```

Since the purpose of `sed` is process text line by line, it's not usual or at least a good idea to try to match new lines.

Answer (score 1):

Taking the question literally without trying to figure out what is *actually* happening:

```
$ cut -d ' ' -f -2 file | paste -d ' ' - <( printf '%s\n' AAA BBB CCC )
Var_A = AAA
Var_B = BBB
Var_C = CCC
```

This discards the values after the equal signs in the original file using `cut`, and then attaches new values produced by `printf` using `paste`.

---

Using `sed` (and `printf` and `paste`):

```bsh
printf '%s\n' AAA BBB CCC | paste -d @ file - | sed 's/\(= \).*@/\1/'
```

This produces the complete original file and the new data side by side with the two sets delimited by `@` characters like so:

```
Var_A = 1@AAA
Var_B = 2@BBB
Var_C = 3@CCC
```

`sed` is then used to replace everything between `=` and `@` on each line with `=` .

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to use the arrays, the following solution may be of use:

```
$ v=([1]=AAA BBB CCC)
$ cat <<. | sed -e "s/1/${v[1]}/
> s/2/${v[2]}/
> s/3/${v[3]}/"
> Var_A = 1
> Var_B = 2
> Var_C = 3
> .
Var_A = AAA
Var_B = BBB
Var_C = CCC
```

You can modify the search part to the variables of choice and then, substitute.